# MULE - order of precedence for application properties vs VM Args vs env variables

Tags: environment-variables, mule, properties-file, vmargs

I need to know the order of precedence of application properties, VM arguments and system environment variables in mule application whenever we have same property defined in all the 3 places

I referred few documentations and articles. It is mentioned that the order is

**application.properties > VM Arguments > System environment variables**

But when I tested, I see below as the precedence

**VM Arguments > System environment variables > application.properties**

Can someone confirm me which is the correct one?

Comment: Which exact version of Mule is this questions for?

Comment: @aled, I'm using Mule 3

Answer (score 1):

After running through series of tests I have found following priority:

1. VM Arguments
2. Program Arguments
3. System environment variables
4. application.properties
5. Global Property in application config